# How to fix flash objects in specific location in the stage no matter how i resize the flash file

Tags: actionscript, adobe-flash-cs3

I'm working on a project but i have a problem 
I have an object inside my flash file and i want to lock the object on 0 x-axis 0 y-axis but when i re-size my SWF file my object's location changed to another location how can i fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean ?

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

Comment: 1119: Access of possibly undefined property stageAlign through a reference with static type flash.display:Stage.

it gives me this error